# Should these questions about Passive/Active checks be marked as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

[Perception Check vs Passive Perception](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99237/perception-check-vs-passive-perception) was posted today and was then closed as a dupe of [Passive Perception confusion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48256/passive-perception-confusion).

My concern is that the initial question (along with [Does passive perception supersede active perception?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48281/does-passive-perception-supersede-active-perception), which was also closed as a dupe of the Passive Perception Confusion question), are not duplicates of the Confusion question.

Neither were questions about understanding the difference between Passive/Active, but asked whether or not Passive acted as a floor for an Active roll - specifically for Perception, but could possibly be used for other skills.

Should those questions be reopened? Should they be handled differently?

Comment: I suspected that it was a dupe, but didn't vote until I saw another vote to close. Was a bit surprised to see only two votes closing it. Will look at all three again later and see if I feel strongly about it being a dupe or not.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I have no issue it being a dupe. It'd that the associated question is alao marked as a dupe, but neither are what those questions ask.

Comment: OK, I'll take a look later when I can concentrate on it.  I +1'd your answer as it was nice and concise, and usable.

Comment: Given the result of debates here and that [Does passive perception supersede active perception?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48281) has been reopened, I'm switching [Perception Check vs Passive Perception](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/99237) to be a duplicate of that instead of [Passive Perception confusion](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48256).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Awesome - thank you! Is there a way to merge? WaxEagles answer is correct, but it's missing the now in existence Crawford interview. Or does it not really matter?

Comment: There is definitely a way to merge — all answers and comments get moved from one to the other — but because there's no “undo” option we don't tend to do it quickly. Let's let it simmer for a bit to ensure there's nothing new to say/do about it, and then in a week or so (if anyone remembers), they can be merged new→old. (A flag on the duplicate is a good way to remind the mods about it later. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the title of the Q is [Perception Check vs Passive Perception](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99237/perception-check-vs-passive-perception), the question body itself doesn't ask for the differences between an active and passive check.

What they are concerned about is, can you use Passive Perception anyway, even if your Perception check result is lower?

> Player 1 has a passive perception of 15. Player 1 does a perception check and rolls a 6. Player 1 still notices what is going on in the area because of their passive perception being 15.
>
> Is this correct?

That is a question already asked and answered in [this question which is also a duplicate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48281/does-passive-perception-supersede-active-perception).

However, the two duplicate questions ([one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48256/passive-perception-confusion) and [two](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48281/does-passive-perception-supersede-active-perception)) are not duplicates of each other. It would be good if they were unlinked.

Comment: The problem is that that particular answer (which was neither highly voted nor chosen as the best) was part of the answer to the confusion question, but that the top answer did not include that in their response. I don't think that if a partially related, but not duplicate, question contains the right answer for another question it should be considered a duplicate.

Comment: @NautArch My point isn't the answer on one answers this question. I'm saying this question is a true duplicate of the linked question. They ask for the same thing phrased in different ways. They're both asking, can you take your Passive Perception if your Perception check is lower than your Passive.

Comment: I may be totally daft, but that question does NOT seem to be asking if they should use the floor for a passive in an active roll. Instead, they are asking whether or not to use Passive or Active: "So what gives? Shall I take it that the DMs ask for the roll because they consider the party to be actively seeking for hidden foes? Or am I just misreading the rulebook and the DM guide?"

Comment: @NautArch Its core question, describing the scenario they are having difficulty adjudicating, is as follows: "*Player 1 has a passive perception of 15. Player 1 does a perception check and rolls a 6. Player 1 still notices what is going on in the area because of their passive perception being 15.*" This directly implies that the player is insisting they cannot roll below their Passive.

Comment: Yes, that's in the question *I* answered. But the question it is ultimately marked a duplicate of does NOT have it in their question. An answer to that question is included in one of the lower voted answers, but it is not in the question itself - nor is it in the higher voted or chosen answer.

Comment: @NautArch You're right. The core issue is the same for all 3 questions -- do I roll Perception or go with Passive? -- but [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48256/passive-perception-confusion) asks it in a worse way than [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48281/does-passive-perception-supersede-active-perception). Meanwhile, [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99237/perception-check-vs-passive-perception) and [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48281/does-passive-perception-supersede-active-perception) are the true duplicates.

Comment: You've convinced me to change my stance. I think the better asked question is [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48281/does-passive-perception-supersede-active-perception) actually, and the other questions should be marked as a duplicate to it instead.

Comment: I still think the floor question should be separate from the how to use question. Are you saying they shouldn't?

Comment: @NautArch It makes sense to *not* make them duplicates. But these questions were made dupes a long time ago, I'm unsure if you are supposed to apply modern-style curation to these. But I can see why they would have been marked duplicates. Knowing how to use active/passive Perception checks will make you realize passive checks are the floor value.

Comment: I agree, but someone looking for the specific question on Perception floor won't necessarily find it by looking for a general perception question. maybe.

Comment: @NautArch That is applying modern curation to a pair of old questions. You can try to re-open the historical duped question and dupe this one to that one. But that sounds like a lot of re-jiggling things. That result makes sense though.

Comment: Agreed - is that a mod thing, or do I need to start to making those requests? If we are in agreement, do you want to update your answer to this?

Comment: @NautArch No, you could do it by re-opening the dupe question (5 people to re-open per question), and then dupe this question to the other one. I imagine mods can do it faster. Answer will be updated.

Comment: Just as a note since it came up in these comments: current curation standards is always a good reason to rejigger old posts/duplicates/etc., since it overall improves the site as a whole.